# Condition render functional component with multiple case and complex logic

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements, react-hooks

I'm new with Functional Component and new Hook feature of React. Currently I have a use case of condition render with complex logic and multiple case (which can not simply use switch case, ternary or enum render). Look at sample code below:

```
const conditionRender = condition => {
  if (condition < 0) {
    return <Component1 />
  }
  if (condition < 12) {
    return <Component2 />
  }
  if (condition < 50) {
    return <Component3 />
  }
  if (condition < 100) {
    return <Component4 />
  }
  if (condition % 2 === 0) {
    return <Component5 />
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    {conditionRender(condition)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I'm using the function outside function component for this. Is this the best practice? or you can suggest best for this. Thank you

Comment: There is no react specific best practice for this. What you are doing is ok.

Comment: This looks like a perfectly valid pattern to use for your case. You could use a `switch` statement too, but it's functionally the same - just depends on personal preference.

Comment: see also here for further infos on conditional rendering (but your example is fine): https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Thanks for well reply, just suppose to have any other better way

Answer (score 0):

Just return a null value in the last because if none of the condition matches then it will not return anything

```
const conditionRender = condition => {
  if (condition < 0) {
    return <Component1 />
  }
  if (condition < 12) {
    return <Component2 />
  }
  if (condition < 50) {
    return <Component3 />
  }
  if (condition < 100) {
    return <Component4 />
  }
  if (condition % 2 === 0) {
    return <Component5 />
  }
return null
}
```

Comment: Yes, I missed it in the sample code, but this is not the issue I've mentioned, by the way, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: @QuocVanTang I didn't see any issue in the description you posted. just I see the final return is missing so that's why I posted this. other than that everything is good

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method to do this with Hooks is following this path.

**App.js**

```js
<ConditionalComponent comp={"ex1"} />
<ConditionalComponent comp={"ex2"} />
```

---

**ConditionalComponent.js**

```js
export default function ConditionalComponent(props) {
        return (
            <>
                {props.comp === "ex1" && <h1>Example 1<h1/>}
                {props.comp === "ex2" && <h1>Example 2<h1/>}
            </>
        )
}
```

Don't forget about imports!